# Inserting multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to insert two or more columns in a table from a SELECT statement?

E.g.
If i do two insert:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(dist0)
SELECT min(term1)
FROM graph_path
WHERE distance = 0
GROUP BY term2_id
ORDER BY term2_id;
```

AND

```
INSERT INTO temp_table(dist1)
SELECT min(term1)
FROM graph_path
WHERE distance = 1
GROUP BY term2_id
ORDER BY term2_id;
```

The result is:

```
dist0    dist1
1
2
3
          4
          5
          6
```

How can i get a result like this? :

```
dist0   dist1
1         4
2         5
3         6
```

Postgresql version 9.5

AS ASKED:
E.g. with term2_id

```
select term2_id, min(term1_id)
from graph_path
where distance = 1
group by term2_id
order by term2_id;
```

RESULT:

```
term2_id   min
2          1507
3          107 
5          1
```

Comment: We insert rows, not columns. But what columns does the temp table have? You need a select that returns these (3) rows. Show us the output of the selects after including the `term2_id` in the select lists.

Comment: Done as you asked =)

Comment: And the first query?

Comment: For distance = 0 the result is as  term2_id just because is the first term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We insert rows, not columns, in a table.

You need a query that returns both results, combined in 3 rows. Assuming that the `term2_id` values should match:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table
  (dist0, dist1)
SELECT 
  min(term1) FILTER (WHERE distance = 0),
  min(term1) FILTER (WHERE distance = 1)
FROM graph_path
WHERE distance IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY term2_id
ORDER BY term2_id ;
```